# Payfort payment gateway integration in android

Tags: android, sdk, payment-gateway, payfort

I'm having trouble with payfort sdk integration in android. The documents they provided are not sufficient to build a complete structure. If anybody has done this, please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What IDE do you use? which part of the integration you are struggling with? also you can contact the support team for any further help.

Comment: I'm using android studio. I'm getting sdk token and don't know next step. There's nothing in the document.

Comment: the integration guide is explaining the whole flow. double check the api online guide

Answer (score 0):

https://testfort.payfort.com/api/?java#fort-mobile-sdk follow this guide.. Firs Get sdk token and then u can do next payfort operations like purchase.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate PAYFORT mobile payment SDK you need to contact the support team and assign ur company as a merchant account on the FORT, to be able to integrate the SDK.

If you already have an account on the FORT, you can access the Mobile SDK files and the SDK integration guide directly. Otherwise having the file is useless.

Happy coding.